# formControl.value returns null although there is a "value" key in formControl object

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a fairly complicated form with a plenty of controls in it, and i want to get value one of those inside formGroup.valueChanges subscription callback. (sample code below)

So i do a simple console.log(this.control) and it returns control which always definitely contains a "value" key with value in it, let's say "26".

However, when i try to get this value with console.log(this.control.value) in some occasions it returns null.

I tried to use setTimeOut and it works well, but it doesn't seem to me as a right way to fix the problem.

What's the secret of such behaviour?

```
this.someFormGroup.valueChanges .pipe(first()) .subscribe(() => {       
   console.log(this.control)   // form control with value:'26' in it.
   console.log(this.control.value); // null
   setTimeout(() => {   // works well
      console.log(this.control)   // form control with value:'26' in it.
      console.log(this.control.value)  // '26;
    });
})
```

Comment: Why you subscribe to form value changes and instead of checking the value change 
( f.e. .subscribe(data => console.log('form data change', data) )  you check the control value? 

It's an async operation so the value is just not there when you console.log(this.control.value). If you want to observe just this control value change then you should subscribe to this control valueChanges instead of whole formGroup

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it makes it clear. But can you explain how come that there is a "value" key with value in formControl then? is this different entity than the one that formControl.value refers to?

Comment: There is a value but it is not accessible at the time when you invoke console.log(this.control.value). 
console.log(this.control) despite it is shown in the value parameter it's not bubbled yet to have access to it. You can think of it as in the meantime you triggered this console.log method it was filled but when you want to have direct access to it it's not there yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have access to "this.control.value" you should observe valueChanges of only this control or if you need the whole form context you should just observe changes instead of checking any control separately cause the value might not be bubbled to this control value as it is an async method.

```
this.someFormGroup.valueChanges.pipe(first()).subscribe(data =>          
   console.log(data)  // show whole formGroup data change
})
```

or

```
this.control.valueChanges.pipe(first()).subscribe(data =>          
   console.log(data)  // show control data change
})
```